# What happens when you declare a callback with wrong amount of parameters in C?

Tags: c, pointers, callback

So, I'm implementing a functionality in the Company I work for, and I'm having some doubts about callbacks and function pointers. Here is an example code:

```
struct callback {
    int (*func) (int *, int);
};

static struct callback cbstruct;

void install_func(struct callback *cbstruct, int (*func) (int *, int))
{
    cbstruct->func = func;
}

int write(int *integ)
{
    return *integ;
}

int main() {
    int * a = malloc(sizeof(a));
    *a = 5;

    install_func(&cbstruct, write);

    printf("%d\n", (cbstruct.func)(a,3));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this program registers a callback for a structure using a function pointer. It is expected that the function receives two parameters (int* and int), but in the example code, the "write" function receives only an int *.

I would expect it to give me a compilation error, but there's only a warning:

```
funcpointer.c:24:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘install_func’ from incompatible pointer type
install_func(&cbstruct, write);
                          ^
funcpointer.c:10:6: note: expected ‘int (*)(int *, int)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(int *)’
void install_func(struct callback *cbstruct, int (*func) (int *, int))
     ^
```

This program apparently runs correctly, printing 5 on the screen, but I'm not sure if it is correctly written, considering the difference in parameters amount on definition and declaration.

Why does it compile and work (apparently)? Is there an imminent problem by doing this? I'm not sure what happens to the second argument (3) that is called from main.

I'm asking this question because I recently changed the signature of a callback (adding a parameter), and I was expecting to see many errors from where this callback was called, but I just got some warnings and the program continued to (apparently) run correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: It compiles because it is doing a cast of one function pointer type to another function pointer type.  You should make the change to your function.  And you should probably avoid using 'write' to not conflict with the standard library write function.

Comment: what is malloc(sizeof(a));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard C11 at §6.3.2.3 specifies:

> 8. A pointer to a function of one type **may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again**; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined**.

So you are allowed to convert between function pointers of different types, but it is clearly stated that this brings undefined behavior if the call is not compatible with the referenced pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which side the mismatch is on.  If the callback expects 1 param, but 2 are passed to it, the callback will read the first and ignore the second.  Since the caller is responsible for setting up and tearing down the call, there are no problems.

But the reverse can give you undefined behavior.  If the callback expects 2 params, but the caller only thinks it needs 1, then the second will not have been set up, so it's value is "undefined" (whatever happens to be in the memory location for second param).

Comment: The first case doesn't incur into UB as long as the calling convention let to the caller the responsibility of clearing the stack (as in `__cdecl`) but wouldn't work with a different calling convention (eg `__stdcall`) in which the callee is responsible of stack.